Linking identity providers in keycloak without keycloak credentials
In Keycloak, I'm trying to implement SSO login using services like Okta and OneLogin. Currently, when I attempt an SSO login for the first time, it directs me to an IDP linking page. At this stage, if I provide Keycloak credentials, the IDP gets linked to the account. I would like to know if it's possible to bypass this step?

I tried modifying the first broken login flow, but nothing worked.
Update:
I added a user in Keycloak without setting a password, as I want this user to log in only via Okta. I have configured Okta as an identity provider in Keycloak. When the user tries to log in via the Keycloak page, it redirects to Okta. After successful authentication, it redirects back to Keycloak, which then requests Keycloak credentials to link the Okta IDP to that user. In this case, setting a password is not feasible for me. Is there a way to automatically link the IDP upon successful authentication from Okta, without asking for Keycloak credentials? Although there is a GUI for manual linking, I don’t have the IDP user ID.

Update :
I was able to figure it out
Solution:


I can help you if you tell more about, what are you trying to achieve after bypassing? I have done similar thing for my requirement.

I have made changes in the question
